# "Padding" не работает в "bootstrap row"

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

Добавлен `bootstrap` и `jquery`.

**Index.php**

```
<div  class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="q1" class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <label id="q2">Ass</label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Пробовал добавить `Padding` на `label` из `css.css`

```
#q1{    background-color: #ffe6e6;
}

#q2{background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 50px 30px 50px 80px;
}
```

и вот результат [image: рез]
Так как я могу это исправить?

Comment: Ass мда .......

Comment: не воспроизводится https://jsfiddle.net/6kf9L8qb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование тега label жизненно необходимо? Вообще не к месту уберит его и должно заработать. И само собой надо стили все в q1 перенести

Comment: убрал **label**!! не работает

Comment: Sv__t  так в результате то что у вас получилось запостите и стили и html

Comment: в **index.php** `<div id="q1" class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        Ass
        </div>`       
             ..  .....................................
   ..                                                                              
 в **css.css** `#q1{    background-color: #ffe6e6;
    padding: 50px 30px 50px 80px;`
}

Comment: StepHan Кэш чистили? Ctrl+F5 попробуйте на странице так должно работать https://jsfiddle.net/zsdrf14v/